# How to calculate the flow rate and kinetic energy of gas flowing in a pipe given its density, the pipes diameter and its velocity

Tags: mechanical-engineering, chemical-engineering

I've been given a question which asks to calculate the kinetic energy of gas flowing through a pipe given the density(kg/m^3), pipe diameter(m) and velocity(m/s).

I'm first required to find the flow rate(m^3/s) then find the kinetic energy(Joules) of the stream.

Any formulas or advice about how to approach this question would be greatly appreciated?

Answer (score 1):

Apply the continuity equation: mass in is equal to mass out

so (density * area * speed) for the inlet is equal to the (density * area * speed) for the outlet.

Do make sure that the units used are coherent. Then consider laminar or turbulent flow.

Also links like this may help: https://myengineeringtools.com/Piping/Fluid_Velocity.html